# Laravel won't reload .env file on MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel, mamp

I recently switched from using the built-in Apache2, and PHP installation on Mac, and changed to the newest version of MAMP (3.5) and moved all of my projects into the htdocs folder. Everything works fine except for my Laravel projects after I update to the new MySQL info. When trying to access anything that uses the MySQL, I get this error

`PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'cumc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

The new .env file looks like this in the database information.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cumc
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

So by the error, it looks like something is getting cached, but I've run every cache:clear command I could find, restart MAMP, my Mac, and tried everything I can think of. Even changing the `app/database.php` with the new details, and changing the name of `.env` so it wouldn't load, and it still shows the error.

Here's the `config/database.php` file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: Try to change details In Config->database.php  and as well in .env file
after that use this command php artisan serve

Comment: @PardeepPathania is that the only way Ill be able to get it to work is by using `php artisan serve`? Cause I was hoping MAMP would allow me to just run it directly without having to do that.

Comment: 1) Do one thing try to create virtual host. it may solve your problem

Comment: @PardeepPathania How do I set that up in MAMP. Im not using the Pro version.

Comment: use this http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php                           or this https://medium.com/@danilosapad/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-on-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite-afac19e982cf#.x65ykvqbk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `php artisan config:clear`, it will clear cached configuration.

Comment: I've run that 3 times, and then restarted the MAMP server, and its still giving the same error.

Comment: I added it. It should be the same as a fresh install.

Comment: Try to run `php artisan cache:clear`. Also, delete all files from `bootstrap/cache` and run `composer dumpauto`

Comment: I ran the commands, removed the files, and restarted the server, and its still using the same credentials. Its just not making sense where its storing this now. Should I try and reinstall larval with my composer file?

Comment: @hightekjonathan, try to use full text search on Laravel project folder, search for `cumc`, maybe you'll find something interesting.

Comment: I did a whole project source, and even the search showed that `.env` had the new credentials. I also searched for the old password and it showed no results. i even manually changed the credentials in the `laravel/.../connector.php` file and its still giving the error. So its looking like it may be a weird cache issue with apache maybe?

Comment: I doubt it. Do not search for password, search for the user `cumc`.

Comment: I searched for cumc globally and it only showed up in my views as anchor tags, and in the .env as the selected database. But nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Same behavior with Mamp Pro in 2021.
In fact, config is stored in sessions.
Solve it by deleting content of storage/framework/sessions/ if sessions saved in files.
If saved in DB ( for instance, mysql ) just empty the right table.
and so on :)